# pythonPath for python-shell is not working after when electron is build

Tags: python, electron, electron-builder

I'm using electron app to run python scripts using python-shell. I have set *pythonPath* to my anaconda env shown below. This works find when I run the app but after packing the app with electron-builder, it shows the following error: *No such file or directory found* even I'm using absolute path on the same PC.

```
const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');
const path = require('path');

const options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonPath: 'C:/Users/nauma/.conda/envs/YOLO/python.exe',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
    scriptPath: path.join(__dirname, '/build/engine/')
  };

  PythonShell.run('index.py', options, function (err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(res);
  });
```

Exception after building app is shown below:

[[image: 1]]

Answer (score 0):

- on windows when not setting pythonPath,

  python shell could find by itself the path to python,

  potentially using an env var or registry key.
- But to make sure my electron app would run everywhere,

  I prefered to embed python using a specific configuration

  for electron builder to bundle python

package.json:

```
"build": {
    "appId": "angular_electron.id",
    "extraFiles": [
      {
        "from": "resources/${os}",
        "to": "Resources",
      }
    ]
  }
```

and calling python using the right resourcepath:

```
import { isPackaged } from 'electron-is-packaged';
const resourcesPath = isPackaged
    ? join(rootPath, './resources')
    : join(rootPath, './resources', getPlatform());

pyshell.PythonShell.run('hello.py', 
    {pythonPath:join(resourcesPath,'/python-3.6.3-embed-amd64/python.exe'),scriptPath:join(resourcesPath,'/bin')}, 
    function  (err, results)  {
      if  (err)  throw err;
      console.log('hello.py finished.');
      console.log('results:', results);
     });
```